# Proposing feature requests to the R Core Team

Tags: r, open-source

What's the recommended way/workflow of contacting the R Core Team in order to propose feature requests?

By "feature requests" I do not simply mean firing something like "I'd like to see functionality XY doing XY, so it'd be cool if you'd go ahead and implement that for me" but proposing actual code instead.

I love R and am willing to contribute, share code and all. Yet sometimes I find it a bit hard to figure out just exactly ***how*** to contribute ;-) I've looked at the [R Project Developer Page](http://developer.r-project.org/) and used the r-devel mailing list a couple of times. Especially with respect to the latter, I've gotten the impression that it's not the right place / not desired to elaborate one's feature request with actual code (which can sometimes be more than just a two liner). So I wonder if there's a "better" or more "systematical" way in order to do that.

### EDIT 2011-11-09

I was asked to provide a short example:

I'm using S4 Reference Classes extensively and implemented a lot of little utility functions for my objects. One such utility function is some sort of a "reset" functionality:

```
setRefClass(
    "A", 
    fields=list(a="numeric", b="character"),
    methods=list(
        reset=function(fields=NULL, ...){
            temp <- new("A")
            if(is.null(fields)){
                fields <- names(getRefClass("A")$fields())
            }
            sapply(fields, function(x){
                .self$field(name=x, value=temp$field(x))        
            })
            return(TRUE)
        }
    )
)

x <- new("A", a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])

x$a
x$b
x$reset(fields="a")

x$a
x$b

x$reset()
x$a
x$b
```

Quite often, it's not the fanciest feature in the world that pops up on my "oh, that's missing" list. Plus it might be such a "singular" function that developing a whole package sometimes feels like cracking the nut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: @JasonMArcher: fair enough, although I'm glad the question will remain (because it's actually useful, even if off-topic). (Your link seems a little bit off-topic, although I guess at a big stretch you could consider this a "customer support" question ...)  (Did you downvote all the answers here?  They each have exactly one downvote ... if so, that seems a little extreme since the downvote is (I guess) supposed to indicate that the answer is "not useful" ...?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a great question. While really liking R a lot, I find its development model frustrating at times. I would say the best options are

0. (Based on a comment from @Matifou) Check whether your idea has been previously discussed on `r-devel@r-project.org`. Although the archives don't provide a search interface, you can do a Google search prefixed with `site:stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel` (e.g. `site:stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel sweep`). Nabble also provides a searchable interface but is ugly and ad-heavy ...
1. post the initial idea (without extensive code) to R-devel and see if you can get discussion/enthusiasm going. You have to be willing to push: for example, I managed to get some additional error-checking incorporated in `sweep` a few years ago (having it actually complain about mismatched dimensions rather than silently returning the wrong answer), but only after proposing the idea; waiting a week; re-raising the idea; sending some prototype code; testing it to make sure it didn't cause a performance hit; further discussion ...
2. implement your idea as an add-on package.  This is of course much harder if what you propose is a change to core R functionality (on the other hand, that kind of change will also be much harder to get accepted).  On the other hand, you can implement just about anything you want in an add-on package, and it has several advantages. (1) Your code will be available for everyone to use immediately (if you post on R-forge, Rforge, GitHub, or CRAN); (2) it is a way for the ideas to get developed and refined *without* buy-in from R core; (3) even if it never gets accepted in R-core, it will still be around as a package.
3. Try to find an existing utility or "misc" package to contribute to (for example, I have contributed to Jim Lemon's `plotrix` package, which is a compilation of small plotting utilities), and contact the maintainer/author.
4. Post your wish-list items to the R bug tracker (with code attachments etc.).  However, they will get seen by many fewer people than if you use options #1 or #2, and as a result are more likely to languish in the bug tracker without ever seeing the light of day.

Comment: I started to write my own packages. Yet, I often stumble across something so small that wouldn't really justify a whole package of its own. Of course you could always solve this by publishing "yet another utility package", but I wonder if that's really the way we should be headed as you easily lose track, people use different conventions, problem of masking (which I think is terrible as sometimes you don't even know it happened until you need to refactor your code ;-)) and so on...

Comment: See (revised) suggestion #3 above.  In the example you give I would probably post to R-devel, inquiring whether someone is working on a suitable utility package.  By posting on r-devel you might also attract the attention of John Chambers, who I believe is the main developer behind reference classes ...

Comment: Nice answer.  I would add that a good code submission contains not just code, but also high quality documentation as well as automated test code (where applicable).

Comment: Ah, I cannot agree with you more! I have almost given up the idea of wrestling with R core for new features, and to write an add-on package can save me lots of efforts. I have a dream that one day the good old R development can move to a more "open" place like GitHub, so programmers can contribute way way way easier than the current clunky system of bugzilla + svn + email...

Comment: Point 1 could also include step 0: investigate whether `r-devel` has already discussed your issue. Even this step is not trivial: the standard archive (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/) does not seem to allow for a search. Searchable alternatives exist but are not easy to find, see for example: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-devel-f909078.html

Answer (score 29):

You are very unlikely to get new features into base R itself, unless i) it piques the interest of one of the R Core Development Team, or ii) is an extension of existing functionality that improves the way it works or makes it more efficient *and* a member of R Core is sufficiently interested. You can of course file a bug under the **Wish list** criterion, and provide code, but do not be surprised if the R Core Team don't accept totally new features even if they come with code.

The reasons for this stance have been discussed before; Even if you provide code implementing new feature X for inclusion in R, you are passing the maintenance burden on to the R Core Team and these guys have limited resources and time to do this. The R Core Team effectively develop the base of R for their own interests/research/needs.

As R packages are almost first-class citizens, there is little reason to even ask R core to implement or include your code for feature X. So, as others have said, implement your ideas features in your own package *or* contribute them to another package that already provides code related to your new feature X.

Even incredibly useful packages that are widely used, e.g. **data.table** are unlikely to make it into base R in the short-medium term because they increase the complexity of the code base, have a maintenance burden on the R Core Team, and/or are not drop in replacements for existing code; **data.table** provides a data frame-like extension that is incredibly fast and better suited to large data sets and "queries" on those data. It is not compatible with R's data frame though, employing different conventions. It works well as a package and can continue to do so as such without needing to be *in* R.

The above describes the situation as I see it for new features. For bug reports, file a bug report! Then consider following up with further discussion on R-Devel quoting the bug report ID. Patches provided to support your bug report will make it easier for bugs to be fixed or new features/enhancements added. The patch should include both the R sources that need changing plus a patch to any documentation that needs to change as a result. The patch should be against the SVN tree found at [the R SVN server](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/). As @BenBolker mentions in the comments, bug reports are best filed in R's bug reporting website. Any discussion of the bug on R-Devel should link to the bug report. This way bugs don't fall into cracks and get missed.

Comment: thanks for the insight! The "increased complexity combined with limited ressources" aspect makes sense.

Comment: +1 The maintenance burden issue is quite important.  Few people like to maintain their own code, much less something they've inherited.  On the other hand, a simplification of code that makes it easier to maintain and extend may be very welcome.  In my experience (not with R, but other software) that is usually achieved via some very clever refactoring or some creative abstraction of functionality.  Also, useful test cases or examples may be very welcome: these indirectly reduce maintenance effort and related distractions.

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't completely agree with the last paragraph. It frustrates the hell out of me that people are discouraged from using the bug tracker and instead send bug reports to r-devel where they can easily slip through the cracks and cannot easily be searched. (This is mostly a complaint against R-core for their effective discouragement by yelling at people who post non-bugs in good faith, not with you.)

Comment: I agree that the bug tracking system is a little broken.  We could do with some non-R-core support people (phd students?) who could help with the bug tracking workload so the R-core don't get so grumpy about responding.

Comment: @RichieCotton, contact me off-list (I'm googlable) if you're interested in pursuing this further.

Comment: @BenBolker +1 Quite right - I see the wording I used is not quite as intended. Will edit. Using the Bug Tracker is very important. Discussion of said bug/wish once filed could be conducted on R-Devel. Or discussion could precede submission if insights from the R development community might inform a bug report / feature request.

Comment: Not only does R-core yell at people who post non-bugs, but also at people who post bugs.  One time I found an identical bug in S-Plus and R.  Insightful said, "Thanks for reporting this!".  R-core said something like "this is NOT a bug and we won't fix it".  Other incidents have similarly left me rather soured on using the bug tracker.

Comment: A useful post from Duncan Murdoch about how/why/when one R-core member thinks you should post a bug report: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/33987

Answer (score 17):

The usual way is to write a package, and get it onto CRAN. (All announcements sent to the package list get copied to rhelp.) Then using demonstrating its productive use on rhelp (or perhaps SO) will get it noticed. I'm thinking here of the efforts over the years of Hadley Wickham, Dirk Eddelbuettel, Terry Therneau, Gabor Grothendieck, Frank Harrell, and Matthew Dowle, to name the first six contributors coming to mind who have made my R efforts more productive. Actually as I was writing that list, it kept getting longer and I apologize to several other people that have made contributions I use often.

Comment: David, first off my hat is off to you for your continued prensence on r-help.  You are doing yeoman's work.  Truly appreciated.

Comment: Here Here! I am constantly amazed at your capacity to handle R-help questions, David.

Comment: Thanks guys ... I'm still trying to learn what all these kewl scales are on my slide rule. Especially this LL3 scale.

Answer (score 15):

At useR this year, Brian Ripley told an anecdote that explains the R-core team's stance.  He said he accepted a two line patch to a function from a well respected R programmer ([John Chambers](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/John_Chambers_%28statistician%29), if I remember rightly).  The two lines of code contained three bugs (!), which he then had to fix.  Since then, R-core's default position is to refuse feature requests for R-base, even those with supplied code.  (Bug fix requests are fine, as long as you've treble-checked that it really is a bug.  Use the [R Bug Tracking System](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/) for this.)

While it isn't impossible to get something into R-base it is almost always significantly (p < 1e-6) easier to create a package yourself or add to an existing one.

Comment: Isn't John Chambers an R core *member* ??  (Couldn't he just check his buggy code into the SVN server himself?)

Comment: @Ben: He certainly is now.  Either this was a while ago or I've remembered the name wrongly.  My brain assures me that the rest of the anecdote is accurately recalled.

Comment: He has been for _years_.

Comment: The real problem is the lack of unit testing infrastructure in r core. Code maintenance is fiendishly difficult without it. (Which now why I request tests if you provide a patch for one of my packages)

Comment: @hadley: Is there something like a "guideline to unit testing" in R? I first came across this term looking at some Ruby on Rails stuff and realized that this is the way to go to build a robust piece of software. IIRC you wrote a package for unit testing, right?

Comment: There's some documentation around testthat and RUnit, but mostly you'll need to look at other programming languages. R core tends to use regression tests