# Improving help in R

Tags: r, documentation

I always wander what other people say about the R help. Finally after some years of using, I decided that it is probably time to try to do something about it, because the feeling of gritting teeth does not go away with years of usage. :) Moreover, I think it is one of the few things where R does not kick asses to the other statistical softwares. So, to the point:

I get the feeling (by some experience with learning programming languages when I am not primarily a programmer but economist/statistician) that structure of help really helps and I would like to have it to go in the way

- basic syntax (by basic I really mean only the necessary arguments)
- example for "dummies", to see what it does
- click-here-if-you-want-to-know-more menu/button

The best documentation that I ever used is probably one of Mathematica, look for example here -- ok, because I am new it prevents me from posting more than two links, so look for reference wolfram for Fit command (it is somehow related to the stuff below).

So what I did is that I took R help file for Fitting Linear Models ( http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lm.html ) and put it into some more readable shape for me.
So I built some other version (actually two) look at http://pinda.sifruje.cz/ . The "original" is just the same text taken and only some basic stuff solved (on my 27 inch monitor, if I make the browser full screen the original help is almost unreadable, because it stretches from one end to the other. Next we already have some pretty good fonts so why not to use them, here Linux Biolinum, and I did some to me aesthetic changes...). The "custom" goes a bit deeper and tries to implement a bit more of my thoughts. The buttons are really made quickly and only as an example. Also I do not claim that the code is anywhere good, I spent like hour or two just sawing some pieces that already lay around web. Just take it as some demonstration.

What I would like to receive from you is your opinions about this topic. The stuff that I did is pretty easy to do even algorithmically (some parser could probably parse the existing help files). The only added value here is making important stuff more visible. I also added the "dummies" example.

So please tell me what you think. I am a bit busy and if I do anything with it I would like to have it thought through carefully beforehand. Also if anybody would be interested in helping, or if he is running similar project, tell me.

Thanks,
Tomas.

Comment: Interesting project, but your question isn't really a question, and it's off-topic as well.

Comment: That's neat! But this isn't really the sort of question we look for on SO, so don't feel bad if this is closed quickly. Some folks on R-help might find it interesting though.

Comment: Before this gets closed let me suggest that it's my impression that relatively few of the people who would be needed to buy into this and implement it are readers of SO/[R]. The decision-makers for R are all reading the r-devel mailing list.

Comment: Agree with @joran.  You might look into integrating this into the JGR interface, or RStudio, or Deducer.  I think the chances of R-core ever agreeing to make this a core part of R are very small, but there are other ways to disseminate this kind of improvement. (See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065835/proposing-feature-requests-to-the-r-core-team )

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at some of the other things that have been tried, especially the `helpr` package which works inside of R, and some of the community based web sites that try to address help (crantastic.org, cranberries (http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/), and various wikis)

Comment: As someone who frequently is tasked with parsing R help pages to colleagues, I think this is a great concept and hope to see it keep momentum. I agree with others that SO may not be a great fit for this though. Along with the notions above, you can look into getting some more traction with the r-bloggers website and try to build some buzz around this before UseR! this summer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

*R help system does not "kick ass" compared to other statistical packages?*

What other packages are we talking about? Stata? SAS!? What is a "good" help system is very subjective. Some will call for verbosity, some will say parsimonious.

Indeed, many R help entries can seem cryptic. Taken from the "Description" of the seq() function (a relatively simple function):

> "Generate regular sequences.  ‘seq’ is a standard generic with a
>        default method.  ‘seq.int’ is a primitive which can be much faster
>        but has a few restrictions.  ‘seq_along’ and ‘seq_len’ are very
>        fast primitives for two common cases."

The first sentence describes all you need to know. The rest is very cryptic, until you start learning language definitions. Besides, you do not need to understand this kind of information for mere usage of most functions. It becomes relevant when developing new methods and classes. Help entries are not meant to be read in their entirety. It depends on your purpose.

["R Language Definition"](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) manual is a good introduction to this terminology.

I do not doubt that a few additional examples could be contributed to the official documentation. What is insightful to the statistician may not be so for the econometrician and vice-versa.

Comment: I'm normally among the first to defend R, but in this case I have to disagree.  R help files tend to be pretty bad, and the example you quoted is bad even for those who understand what it's saying.  I agree that help files are written for multiple audiences, etc., but the first thing they should do is tell you how to use a function.  After that you can get into the technical details of how to modify/debug the function.

Comment: OTOH, a few well-chosen examples placed at the end of the help page often do more to teach usage than reams of dialog.